# Project Euler Problem 8: Largest product in a series

Tags: c#, beginner, programming-challenge

The problem statement is as follows:

> The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product are 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.
>
> 73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
>   96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
>   85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
>   12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
>   66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
>   62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
>   30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
>   70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
>   65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
>   52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
>   53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
>   83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
>   82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
>   16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
>   17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
>   24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
>   07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
>   84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
>   05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
>   71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
>
> Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product. What is the value of this product?

My code below solves the problem.
I know this enters into the realm of preference but is it taboo to merge the 100 digit number onto a single line as I initially did but commented out, or is the method utilizing `StringBuilder` for "readability" better?

```
public class Program
{       
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //string numbers = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
        string numbers = Get100DigitNumber();

        Console.WriteLine(MaxProductNumericStringOfLength(numbers,13));
    }

    static long ProductOfNumericString(string number)
    {
        long product = 1;
        for (int digit = 0; digit<number.Length ; digit++)
        {
            product *= int.Parse(number[digit].ToString());
        }
        return product;
    }

    static long MaxProductNumericStringOfLength(string numberString, int length)
    {
        long maxSubstring=0;
        long possibleMaxSubstring;
        for (int position = 0; position < numberString.Length-length ; position++)
        {
            possibleMaxSubstring = ProductOfNumericString(numberString.Substring(position,length));

            if (possibleMaxSubstring > maxSubstring)
                maxSubstring=possibleMaxSubstring;
        }

        return maxSubstring;
    }

    static string Get100DigitNumber()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934");
        sb.Append("96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843");
        sb.Append("85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511");
        sb.Append("12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557");
        sb.Append("66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113");
        sb.Append("62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749");
        sb.Append("30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866");
        sb.Append("70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776");
        sb.Append("65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243");
        sb.Append("52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397");
        sb.Append("53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482");
        sb.Append("83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474");
        sb.Append("82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881");
        sb.Append("16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586");
        sb.Append("17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042");
        sb.Append("24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408");
        sb.Append("07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188");
        sb.Append("84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606");
        sb.Append("05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725");
        sb.Append("71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450");

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A better option is to use a constant expression. The text in [7.15 Constant expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691319%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) says:

> A constant-expression is an expression that can be fully evaluated at compile-time.

```
const string number =
    "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934" +
    "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843" +
    "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511" +
    ...
    "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
```

This way the string has not to be constructed at runtime.

Also consider using a [project resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3xhwfctz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for the string or storing the number in a file. See: [Adding and Editing Resources (Visual C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Efficiency consideration:

Each time you call `.Substring()`, a new `string` object is created. String's in C# are immutable (scroll down on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx). You've already seen your code work on 1000 digit numbers, but in the future someone may want to try it with 10,000 digit numbers (or even more!).

String's can be indexed directly using array notation (i.e. `numberString[i]`).

---

Speaking of trying your code with other numbers, I like that your code is split into different methods and the number-getting code is separate from the calculating-code. Good Job!

---

Slight nit-pick: Your method `Get100DigitNumber` is returning a 1000 digit number. Rather than add the missing 0, a better solution would be to come up with a more general name for the method. This will go especially well with Olivier's suggestion to store the number outside the code. That way numbers of varying lengths can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the concern of storing the string,

converting each character to an int is more easily done by simply subtracting `0` from the char value.

a rolling product rather than multiplying 13 digits for each new segment is quite a bit more efficient.

any segment that contains a 0 can automatically be discounted since the product will be 0.  One way to take care of this is by splitting the string using `0` as the separator and removing empty strings.  Using the LINQ extension `Where` gives one the option of eliminating any string less than 13 characters.

```
const string data = "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934" +
                    "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843" +
                    "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511" +
                    "12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557" +
                    "66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113" +
                    "62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749" +
                    "30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866" +
                    "70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776" +
                    "65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243" +
                    "52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397" +
                    "53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482" +
                    "83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474" +
                    "82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881" +
                    "16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586" +
                    "17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042" +
                    "24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408" +
                    "07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188" +
                    "84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606" +
                    "05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725" +
                    "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";

static long GetMaxProduct(int segment)
{
    var segments = data.Split(new char[] { '0' },System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                       .Where(x => x.Length >= segment);
    long maxProduct = 1;
    foreach(string s in segments)
    {
        int i = 0;
        long product = 1;
        for (; i < segment; i++)
        {
            product *= s[i] - '0';
        }
        for (; i < s.Length;i++)
        {
            product = (product / (s[i - segment] - '0')) * (s[i] - '0');
            if(product > maxProduct)
            {
                maxProduct = product;
            }
        }
    }
    return maxProduct;
}
```

Comment: Are you so sure `segment - 1` muls are always more expensive than a div? What makes you assume there will always be at least one run of length `segment` without zeroes? Anyway, good one.

Comment: In my tests doing 12 multiplications operations instead of 1 division and 1 multiplication is at least 3 times slower.  Since for this problem there is only one test case, allowing for edge cases seemed superfluous.  But, the way the function is designed allowing for edge cases would be trivial.

Answer (score 1):

When you've got a hundred characters hardcoded in your code, readability really isn't the issue you should focus on. Don't use the `StringBuilder` just for the sake of making it cute, especially in cases like the Euler Projects where you want your code to run as fast as possible (At least, that's my objective when I do these!).

A method name should always reflect an action. Otherwise you'll you a property. So, if we focus on this, we should change `MaxProductNumericStringOfLength` to something like `FindHighestProductOfConsecutiveNumbers`.

Now, this algorithm is about numbers, not characters. You used the `string` because it would be sooo long to create an array with all the `int`, but you need to change that as "soon" as possible in your algorithm.

Meaning, the `FindHighestProductOfConsecutiveNumbers` should receive a `int[]` or an `IEnumerable<int>`, to your choice.

```
string numberString = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";

//Call ToArray if you want it or not!
IEnumerable<int> numbers = numberString.Select(n => (int)(n - '0'));
```

Doing this, you'll be able to work with what you really want : Numbers. Your code will reflect your intent much better this way.

Answer (score 0):

You are parsing each char to int several times.

I think a rolling product would be more efficient
This is O(n) where you are O(n * 13)

```
private static long MaxProduct2(string input, int len)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
    {
        input = "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934" +
            "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843" +
            "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511" +
            "12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557" +
            "66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113" +
            "62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749" +
            "30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866" +
            "70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776" +
            "65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243" +
            "52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397" +
            "53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482" +
            "83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474" +
            "82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881" +
            "16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586" +
            "17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042" +
            "24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408" +
            "07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188" +
            "84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606" +
            "05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725" +
            "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
    }
    if (input.Length < len)
    {
        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
    }

    long maxProduct = 0;
    foreach (string segment in input.Split(new char[] { '0' }))
    {
        if(segment.Length < len)
        {
            continue;
        }
        //Debug.WriteLine(segment);
        int[] products = new int[segment.Length];
        int count = 0;
        foreach (char c in segment)
        {
            products[count] = int.Parse(c.ToString());
            count++;
        }
        long product = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < products.Length; i++)
        {
            product *= products[i];
            if (i == len - 1)
            {
                maxProduct = product;
            }
            else if (i >= len)
            {                      
                product /= products[i - len]; 
            }
            if (maxProduct < product)
            {
                maxProduct = product;
            }
        }
    }
    return maxProduct;
}
```